# JS countdown timer onload

Tags: javascript

I need to customise a countdown timer to run it on pageload, for now it runs with a play/pause button.

I tried a document.load with this code but it didn't work :

```
 this.classList.remove('play');
 this.classList.add('pause');
 timer(timeLeft);
 isPaused = isPaused ? false : true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infinityweb/k9tg2q1e/98/

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: just call `pauseTimer()` after all your code. (not a very intuitive name, perhaps toggleTimer would be more accurate)

Comment: Its added dynamicaly in the time div in the html code : `<div class="display-remain-time" id="time">05:26</div>`